# How do I read both from keyboard and from file?

Tags: java

I have a Scanner that could be reading from either keyboard or from a file (via pipes), and apparently there's no way to tell which.

I have te following code:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    doStuff();
}
```

That works wonderfully when redirecting input to a file. But if I try to run the program by itself and read from keyboard, it enters an infinite loop. Is there a way to differentiate between reading from keyboard and from a file? Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:
As requested by @Abra, this is what my code looks like with your suggestion:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    String linea = scan.nextLine();
    doStuff();
} while (System.in.available() != 0 && scan.hasNextLine());
```

And here's the command I'm running:

```sh
java -jar Class.jar < File.txt
```

Edit 2:
Solved it, turns out I should only evaluate System.in.available() != 0 once:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean file = System.in.available() != 0;
do {
    String linea = scan.nextLine();
    doStuff();
} while (file && scan.hasNextLine());
```

Comment: Is it an option to react to user inputs with keywords like `"quit"`?

Comment: close() method closes this scanner. break;

Comment: It is a last resort I suppose.

Comment: I can not guess from your code how you are using the same scanner for reading from the file or keyboard. Post the complete/more code to make it clear.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Via pipes like `java TheProgram < someFile.txt`. `System.in` doesn't have to be the keyboard, it's just the standard input stream.

Comment: @Progman - I am not saying that there are no ways . All I'm asking OP is to edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I added "(via pipes)", does that make it clearer?

Comment: @xdan - Yes, it does. Keep it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of `System.in` is `java.io.InputStream`. That class has method `available()`. If you redirect `System.in` to a file, as in

```
myprogram < input_file.txt
```

Then method `available()` returns a number greater than zero (assuming that `input_file.txt` has non-zero size) but when `System.in` refers to the standard input stream, i.e. when you run your program without redirecting standard input, as in

```
myprogram
```

Then method `available()` returns zero.

Comment: That sounds useful. The problem is I can't find a way to get the the InputStream that the scanner is currently using. I've tried storing it previously in a variable, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @xdan what am I missing? This is your code: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`. You **know** that the input stream of your `Scanner` is `System.in`. What do you mean by _I can't find a way to get the the InputStream_ ?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I assumed the stream changes when I redirect the input to a file. My point is that System.in.available() returns zero no matter what I do.

Comment: @xdan [edit] your question and post the command line you are using to run your program and also post a [mcve]. In short, post enough details so that I can try to reproduce the behavior you claim to be seeing.

Comment: Solved it, turns out I should only evaluate System.in.available() != 0 once. Every subsequent evaluation returns false somehow.

Answer (score 3):

The classic practice used commonly in Linux and Unix is to read input from standard input, as you are already doing. In Java, standard input is called `System.in`.

The program reads from standard input and processes what it reads in a loop until it detects end-of-file, which you are already doing.

So your program is not stuck - it is merely waiting for more input or for the end-of-file signal to come from the outside.

If you want to use this program with input from a file, you run it like this:

`myprogram < input_file.txt`

And if you want your program to get its input from terminal (where you type it), you run it just like

`myprogram`

In this case, and after typing your input, you are also responsible to send a special signal from your terminal that will act as a "end-of-file" and will be picked by the program, causing the `while`-loop to exit. Typically, you do this by pressing Control-D.

Keep in mind that reading from standard input is not strictly the same as reading from keyboard. Standard input only knows about text and end-of-file; it has no concept of line editing, testing for when shift key is pressed/released etc.

Answer (score 1):

based on the answer of @Abra you can break the loop if System.in is keyboard so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isKeyboard = System.in.available() == 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            doStuff();
            
            if (isKeyboard) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this stops the code from working properly when reading from file. Thanks tho.

Comment: Why does it break? (Obviously you have to change the assignment to source when you are not reading from System.io). Are you using redirects for reading from file?

Comment: I am using redirects indeed.

Comment: Ok now I understand. The code in the edit should work for you.